# Swift. How to delete the character at the beginning and end of the string?

Tags: swift, string

It is necessary to remove the quotes at the beginning and end of the line, if they are in the line
Could it be more beautiful?

```
var str = "\"Hello, playground\""
let quotes = "\""

if str.hasPrefix(quotes) && str.hasSuffix(quotes) {
    let v = str.dropFirst()
    str = String(v.dropLast())
}
print(str)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like a one liner:

```
let str = "\"\"\"Hello, playground\"\""
let unquoted = String(str.drop(while: { $0 == "\""}).reversed().drop(while: { $0 == "\""}).reversed())
print(unquoted)  //Hello, playground
```

---

You could define these extensions to make it look a tad prettier:

```
extension String {
    private func removeQuotesAndReverse() -> String {
        return String(self.drop(while: { $0 == "\""}).reversed())
    }
    func unquote() -> String {
        return self.removeQuotesAndReverse().removeQuotesAndReverse()
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
let unquoted = "\"\"\"Hello, playground\"\"".unquote()
```

---

If you only need to remove the first and last quotes, if they are both present, then I would only add a check that the count is at least 2 characters, since a string like `"\""` has quotes in both the prefix and suffix, but it's not between quotes:

```
extension String {
    func withoutDoubleQuotes() -> String {
        if self.hasPrefix("\""), self.hasSuffix("\""), self.count > 1 {
            return String(self.dropFirst().dropLast())
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
"\"Hello, playground\"".withoutDoubleQuotes()       //Hello, playground
"\"\"\"Hello, playground\"\"".withoutDoubleQuotes() //""Hello, playground"
"\"".withoutDoubleQuotes()                          //"
"\"\"".withoutDoubleQuotes()                        //
```

Comment: Beautiful! But the second quotation marks are also removed.

Comment: @AndreyZet You mean you only want the first ones to be removed?

Comment: delete first and last if both are present

Comment: I've updated the answer to only take the first and last quotes into account

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collection removeFirst and removeLast mutating methods:

```
var str = "\"Hello, playground\""
let quotes = "\""

if str.hasPrefix(quotes) && str.hasSuffix(quotes) && str != quotes {
    str.removeFirst()
    str.removeLast()
}
print(str)  // "Hello, playground\n"
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan I don't know what you mean by one line. It does what OP asked to mutate the original string and remove both ends it the quotes are present. It also makes sure the original string it is not a single quotes character.

Answer (score -1):

you can do so:

```
let str = "\"Hello, playground\""

let new = str.filter{$0 != "\""}
```

Comment: This would remove all quotes from the string, not just the first and last.